# Why do I get different HTML table sizes?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><table>...</table></td>
   <td><table>...</table></td>
   <td><table>...</table></td>
   ...
   <td><table>...</table></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

which causes a problem represented in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuVaZ/22/). I can easily see that between every `td` in the first level of `table` there is certain space which I do not know where is coming from. The result of this is that the width of the first level table is bigger than the sum of the widths of the second level tables. You can check out the alert popup of the fiddle to see what I mean.

How do I fix this behavior so that I get the same width?

Note: I would also appreciate if an explanation is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add every td first level the css property, the td has the default padding

```
td{
   margin:0; padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to parent table for making widths same:

```
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
```

Working fiddle : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nuVaZ/23/)

And if you want to decrease the white space then please reduce the widths of child tables i.e. around something 300px or something.

Comment: 1. I agree with this but is not supported in HTML5. [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp)
2. I cannot do that as the width is calculated dynamically according the information I have in the _td's_ of the seconds level _table_